# tickformat in Plotly Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly.js, plotly-python

I am trying to format my Plotly Bar Chart x-axis to percentages with 3 decimal points.

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py #for plotting
import plotly.graph_objs as go


y = ['niner', 'deuce', 'checker']
x = [0.03, -0.05, 0.075]


fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(y = y, x = x,
            name = 'returns',
            orientation = 'h',
            marker = dict(color = '#003663',
                             line = dict(
                                      color = '#afafaf',
                                      width = 1.5)
                                    )))

fig.update_layout(
        title = 'Why So Hard Plotly?',
        xaxis = dict(
                tickformat = '%.format.%3f',
                title = 'Returns',
                fixedrange = True,
                hoverformat = '.3f',
                showgrid = True), 

        yaxis = dict(

                fixedrange = True,
                hoverformat = '.3f',
                showgrid = True,

        ),     
         bargap = 0.2, 
         barmode = 'relative',             
)
fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True) 
fig.show()
```

I can get the y-axis to appear as a rounded percentage using `tickformat = '%'`,
but I can't get more decimals to appears. The Plotly d3 documentation isn't clear (to me) how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your x data in the range of 0-1 or 0-100? I.e. do you want the formatted to multiply by 100 for you or not?

Comment: I want to multiply by 100 but with 2 decimal places not 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that setting `tickformat` to `".3%"` should do it. Formatting `0.512345` this way yields `51.235%`.

Comment: Here is a useful page with tickformat examples for reference: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-format

Comment: This wasn't working for my numbered x-axis (sourced from the index of a DataFrame). I got it working by adding `type='linear'` to `update_xaxes()`.